# Programatically linking an image to content (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, media, navigation

When I create a block through views I can easily link it to the content page by setting link image to in the field's settings.  But I also have some blocks that are created programmatically and I would like to similarly add links to these images.  How would I do this?

EDIT: Here is the code I use to create the block:

```
  $block = array();
  $rows = array();
  $format = 'l, F j, Y  - G:i';

  $header = array('Project Name', 'Screenshot' , 'Submitted');
  foreach ($results['node'] as $nid_array) {
    $row = $nid_array->nid;
    $node = node_load($row);
    $path = $node->field_icon_thumbnail['und'][0]['uri'];
      $variables = array(
    'path' =>  image_style_url('icon_thumbnail',$path),
    'alt' => 'Thumbnail',
    'title' => 'Thumbnail',
    'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
    );
      $image = theme('image', $variables);

      $rows[] = array(
    l($node->title, "node/$node->nid"),
    $image,
    date($format, $node->changed)
      );
  }
  $rows = array_reverse($rows);
  $table = array('rows' => $rows, 'header' => $header, 'empty' => 'No terms found');
  $block['content'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('No terms found')
  );
  return $block;
```

Comment: I think you if you make it programmatically you should have nid that related to image so you can link image to node/nid <a href="node/nid"><img/></a>

Comment: Hey Ahmed, I'm not quite sure what I would do with that html snipet.  I have added the code I use to create the block.  Do I need to create my block differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function to wrap the image in a link. As it's HTML you'll need to pass the `html` option to the function so that it isn't run through `check_plain()`:

```
$image = theme('image', $variables);

$linked_image = l($image, "node/$node->nid", array('html' => TRUE));

$rows[] = array(
  l($node->title, "node/$node->nid"),
  $linked_image,
  date($format, $node->changed)
);
```

Comment: Missed that `html => TRUE`, thank you very much. That's what I looked for.